# Radio button best parttern in mobile app

Tags: mobile, design-patterns, radio-buttons

I have radio button selection in mobile app where on selection of it, the dropdown box gets activated. My question is that, is it best practice to place radio button and dropdown in stack manner (pic 1) or horizontal manner(pic 2).
If either of them once followed should we have to maintain the same pattern throughout the app or depends on the context?
[image: pic 1]

[image: pic 2]

Comment: Can you explain the larger context here? It's hard to understand the need to select a radio button to activate a drop down.

Comment: yes...its date selector for ex: current day being the 1st option then followed by last 2 days, last 1 week, current month transactions picker from drop down. only when the user checks the radio button, the drop down activates for the user to pick option.

Comment: Why do they have to first select the radio button?

Comment: because we have 1 more set of radio button below that. On check of each radio button, set of operation will be activated for user to perform.

Comment: Why have the radio buttons at all?

Comment: We're struggling to understand the bigger picture here. Any chance you can sketch out the full set of radios? There might be a more elegant solution that radios.

Comment: So you select the radio belonging to the dropdown you want to choose from, and the other dropdown is disabled, right?

Comment: @jaZRo u got me right!! thats the point... on selection of 1 radio button , other radio and associates disabled.

Answer (score 0):

If you were to follow the principle of progressive disclosure and only showing the information required, you would probably have all the radio buttons grouped together because it is the first action that the user takes. Then depending on which radio button is selected you will have different options displayed for the user to provide further input.

On the other hand, if there is always going to be a dropdown regardless of which radio button is selected (i.e. the next input is of the same data type), then it could be easier to make two dropdowns where you can select from the list of options you already have for the radio button, and then a dropdown for the options that are available based on the first selection.

There is no clear context defined in terms of the overall goal or the design patterns used in the application, so you'll have to make some decisions regarding which design option will provide the most consistent and user-friendly experience.